# Weird results with if-else in a tf.data.map

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Why does the `else` block run when the below script is executed in TF.2.3.1?

```py
DEFAULT_STR = "*"

def add_na_cols(example:Dict, col:str):
    if example[col] == DEFAULT_STR:
        tf.print(example)
        example[f'{col}_na'] = "True"
    else:
        tf.print("Came to false")
        example[f"{col}_na"] = "False"
    return example

t = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({"a": [DEFAULT_STR]})
for r in t.map(partial(add_na_cols, col="a")):
    print(r)
```

Expect to print

```
{'a': "*"}
{'a': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'*'>, 'a_na': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=True'>}
```

but see

```
{'a': "*"}
{'a': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'*'>, 'a_na': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'False'>}
```

Created a collab
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZgLF0ytiRJ4_VwfMMpVRP1TVkV-cFdDc?usp=sharing

```py
def add_na_cols(example:Dict, col:str):
  example[f'{col}_na'] = tf.cond(example[col] == DEFAULT_STR, lambda: "True", lambda: "False")
  return example
```

works but I am trying to know why in graph mode, the `if-else` approach doesn't work as expected

Comment: I had the same qeustion found the answer here. [https://tensorflow.google.cn/guide/function?hl=zh-cn#conditionals](https://tensorflow.google.cn/guide/function?hl=zh-cn#conditionals)